# I can't set a Navigation Property from extern

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have an entity

```
public partial class FUNCTION_METADATA
{
    public FUNCTION_METADATA()
    {
        this.VALUE_METADATA = new HashSet<VALUE_METADATA>();
    }

    public int ID_FUNCTION_METADATA { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<VALUE_METADATA> VALUE_METADATA { get; set; }
}
```

This has an ICollection of VALUE_METADATA.

I tried to load this with an Include-Statement, but I needs 15sec. to load.
So I load the whole FUNCTION_METADATA and in a separate load the whole VALUE_METADATA and want to set the collection in code - that needs 8sec.
But the navigation property doesn't work. In the debugger I have seen an ObjectDisposedException.
How can I set the collection from code without getting an ObjectExposedException when using it?

This is the code with the include - all is working well:

```
LoadAllItemsToCache<FUNCTION_METADATA>(includeProperties: nameof(VALUE_METADATA));
```

And this is the code with two separate loads and some Linq - using Value_METADATA collection is not working:

```
LoadAllItemsToCache<FUNCTION_METADATA>();
LoadAllItemsToCache<VALUE_METADATA>();

var allValueMetadata = GetAllItemsFromCache<VALUE_METADATA>().GroupBy(dvm => dvm.ID_FUNCTION_METADATA).ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList());
var allFunctionMetadata = GetAllItemsFromCache<FUNCTION_METADATA>();

foreach (var functionMetadata in allFunctionMetadata)
{
    if (allValueMetadata.ContainsKey(functionMetadata.ID_FUNCTION_METADATA))
    {
        functionMetadata.VALUE_METADATA = new HashSet<VALUE_METADATA>(allValueMetadata[functionMetadata.ID_FUNCTION_METADATA]);
    }
}
```

The functions LoadAllItemsToCache and GetAllItemsFromCache are part of my DBRepository.

I understand the reasons for an ObjectExposedException comes, but I do not know why it comes here. Why is the Entity trying to get the collection over a context?

Comment: _"Why is the Entity trying to get the collection over a context?"_ - because of lazy loading. There's not enough relevant code in your question to answer this though. Read [ask] and create a [mcve].

Comment: @CodeCaster - but this could be the answer. The DBRepository opens a context, load the entities in the cache and close the context. Now someone must set LazyLoading to false.